# Autocomplete plugin, including words, hashtags, scrolling

Tags: twitter, autocomplete, hashtag

Is there a plugin that can all of those:

1. Autocomplete for simple word (needed for search autocomplete).
2. Autocomplete for hashtags (word that starts with "#")
3. Autocomplete includes dropdown menu, from where user can select with arrows and pressing enter adds the selection to textarea.
4. Autocomplete by part of word not only from the start but from middle of word.
5. Textarea can contain tags and text

1,3,4,5 - Search input field autocomplete.
2,3,4,5 - Hashtags textarea autocomplete.

What I found is:

1. https://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/ - (2) only missed, so we can use it for first paragraph as a separate plugin
2. http://aehlke.github.io/tag-it/examples.html - (1,2,3) missed
3. http://demos.iog3.com/SOTag/ - (1,2,3) missed
4. http://harvesthq.github.io/chosen/ - (1,2) missed
5. https://github.com/webworka/Tagedit - (1,2) missed
6. https://github.com/xoxco/jQuery-Tags-Input - (1,2,3) missed
7. http://documentcloud.github.io/visualsearch/ - (1,4) missed
8. http://nicolasbize.com/magicsuggest/ - (1,2,5) missed
9. http://ioncache.github.com/Tag-Handler/ - (5) missed
10. http://textextjs.com/ - (5) missed
11. http://jcesar.artelogico.com/jquery-tagselector/ - (5) missed
12. http://pietschsoft.com/post/2011/09/09/Tag-Editor-Field-using-jQuery-similar-to-StackOverflow.aspx - (5) missed
13. https://select2.github.io/ - (5) missed
14. https://github.com/bitdrift/tagmate - (4) missed

Comment: https://github.com/yairEO/tagify should be what you looking for

Answer (score 0):

Finally I found what I need, maybe someone need it too:
https://github.com/Hawkers/triggeredAutocomplete

It start to work after small fix and it has all the paragraphs but (1)

After commenting this part of code and adding small CSS it works:

```
    //if ( this.menu.first() && /^previous/.test(direction) ||
    //    this.menu.last() && /^next/.test(direction) ) {
    //    this.menu.deactivate();
    //    return;
    //}
```